# What is the difference between calling _$controller_ instead of _$injector_.get('$controller')?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-mock

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$injector_) {
  ctrl = _$controller_(...) // 1
  ctrl = _$injector_.get('$controller')(...) // 2
}));
```

What are the differences and which way is preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring `_$controller_` in the parameters of the function passed to `inject()` makes the framework inject the $controller service in the function.

Calling `$injector.get('$controller')` explicitly asks the `$controller` service to the framework.

So it's basically the old "dependency injection vs. factory" debate. Should the framework provide the dependency to the test, or should the test ask it dependency to the framework?

The first one is definitely preferrable in production code: it makes your code testable, and is the way you're supposed to use the framework.

In tests, there is no significant difference, although I prefer the first one too.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: How do we get $injector.get('$service') on similar lines ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences in an ES5 context. The first one is the suggested way by Angular, as it is used by them and also in their docs and tutorials.

When you pass a function to `inject`, angular stringifies it and parses fuction parameters to figure out what providers to inject. Then it calls the function with correct providers. For example Angular probably calls `$inject.get` to get the instance of `$controller`.

It makes a difference for ES6 because when you stringify an arrow function, it doesn't start with "function(..." so Angular cannot parse it before Angular 1.5. In that case you need to use array notation: `inject(['$controller', $controller => { ... }])`.